# Dynamically pass querystring to sitemap

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, query-string, sitemap

Hi I has one sitemap in masterpage. I need to dynamic pass querystring to my sitemap. Did anyone get experience with this.
Here is my code

**web.sitemap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Employee Benefit"  description="">

        <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyList.aspx" title="Company list"  description="Company List" >
            <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyDetail.aspx" title="Company Detail"  description="Company Detail" >
                <siteMapNode url="~/Module/EB/Employee/EmployeeDetail.aspx" title="Employee Detail"  description="Employee Detail" />
            </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>

    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Master.aspx

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft New Tai Lue" 
    Font-Size="0.9em" PathSeparator=" : " SkipLinkText="" Font-Bold="False" 
    style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: small" 
    Visible="True" >
        <CurrentNodeStyle ForeColor="#333333" />
        <NodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#284E98" />
        <PathSeparatorStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#507CD1" />
        <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#507CD1" />
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

By the way. my sitemap may have multiple sub siteMapNode. For example

```
 companylist -> companydetail -> EmployeeDetail->.....
```

How can I pass querystring to other sub sitemapNope ?

```
companylist -> companydetail?subID=1 -> EmployeeDetail?subID=2 ->....
```

Comment: If you could provide with more details on how dynamic you want it or a more clear example, that would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please c my latest update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeBehind :

```
   protected string CustomersURL
    {
        get 
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder url = new System.Text.StringBuilder("~/Module/EB/Company/CompanyList.aspx");
            if (condition)
            {
                url.AppendFormat(@"?param1={0}", someparameter);
            }
            return url.ToString(); 
        }
    }
```

.ASPX :

```
    <siteMapNode url='<%# CustomersURL %> title="Company list"  description="Company List" >
```

EDIT :

Check the following explanation from MSDN, it tackles your problem exatly :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178425%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The ExpandForumPaths method is called to handle
    // the SiteMapResolve event.
    SiteMap.SiteMapResolve +=
      new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(this.ExpandForumPaths);
}

private SiteMapNode ExpandForumPaths(Object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    // The current node represents a Post page in a bulletin board forum.
    // Clone the current node and all of its relevant parents. This
    // returns a site map node that a developer can then
    // walk, modifying each node.Url property in turn.
    // Since the cloned nodes are separate from the underlying
    // site navigation structure, the fixups that are made do not
    // effect the overall site navigation structure.
    SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);
    SiteMapNode tempNode = currentNode;

    // Obtain the recent IDs.
    int forumGroupID = GetMostRecentForumGroupID();
    int forumID = GetMostRecentForumID(forumGroupID);
    int postID = GetMostRecentPostID(forumID);

    // The current node, and its parents, can be modified to include
    // dynamic querystring information relevant to the currently
    // executing request.
    if (0 != postID)
    {
        tempNode.Url = tempNode.Url + "?PostID=" + postID.ToString();
    }

    if ((null != (tempNode = tempNode.ParentNode)) &&
        (0 != forumID))
    {
        tempNode.Url = tempNode.Url + "?ForumID=" + forumID.ToString();
    }

    if ((null != (tempNode = tempNode.ParentNode)) &&
        (0 != forumGroupID))
    {
        tempNode.Url = tempNode.Url + "?ForumGroupID=" + forumGroupID.ToString();
    }

    return currentNode;
}


...


// These methods are just placeholders for the example.
// One option is to use the HttpContext or e.Context object
// to obtain the ID.
private int GetMostRecentForumGroupID()
{
    return 24;
}

private int GetMostRecentForumID(int forumGroupId)
{
    return 128;
}

private int GetMostRecentPostID(int forumId)
{
    return 317424;
}
```

You just need to hook to the SiteMapResolveEventHandler on the codebehind of the master page (on the Page_Load event) and provide a function that returns your custom SiteMapNode - such as the ExpandForumPaths in the example - and then pass it as a delegate to the SiteMapResolveEventHandler.

Comment: Hi, i tink tis is not possible to work. cos i load the sitemap from my sitemap.xml Plese c my latest update

Comment: Am sorry i thought it is in the .aspx file. my fault.
But how do you map "SiteMapPath1" to the XML file ?

Comment: I using asp.net sitemap. It map to sitemap.xml automatically

Comment: hey i have Home>Product>Details. after coming to detail page weather i click on home or product i always go to home page i.e the root node. please help