# Modifying nodes in sitemap dynamically to include parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I followed this post [Dynamically pass querystring to sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362769/dynamically-pass-querystring-to-sitemap/17363140#17363140) and got this structure "Home > Product > Details". the parameter which im attaching dynamicallly are not persisting when I go out of the page. For example when I come to product page from home the parameters passed are appended to the node url using the above code. But when I navigate to detail page from Product. then click product on site map the parameters attached before are not saved. Sitemappath control is placed in site master

```
   web.site map 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
 <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="">
 <siteMapNode url="Products.aspx" title="Product"  description="Products" >
 <siteMapNode url="ProductDisplay.aspx" title="Details"  description="Products" />
 </siteMapNode>
 <siteMapNode url="Brands.aspx" title="Brand"  description="Products" >
 <siteMapNode url="ProductDisplay.aspx#1" title="Details"  description="Products" />
 </siteMapNode>
 <siteMapNode url="Designers.aspx" title="Designer"  description="Company Detail" >
 <siteMapNode url="DesignerProductDisplay.aspx" title="Details"  description="DesignerProduct" />
 </siteMapNode>
 <siteMapNode url="Campaign.aspx" title="Campaign"  description="Employee Detail" >
 <siteMapNode url="CampaignProductDisplay.aspx" title="Details"  description="CampPrd" />
 </siteMapNode>
 <siteMapNode url="SignIn.aspx" title="login"  description="CampPrd" />
 <siteMapNode url="Cart.aspx" title="Cart"  description="CampPrd" />
</siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the best method for using a sitemappath control. I recommend creating nodes for each and every link. i.e for each possible value of the parameters passed. else It wont work also if you are building a sitemap for a web crawler this would be pretty much useless.

Source: Experience. faced the same problem recently.

Comment: write a function to query your dp to create the links.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have hooked "SiteMapResolveEventHandler". Make sure to hook this on each post back. It will then bind parameters to each node.

Comment: I already have and the node url gets modified. but when i navigate out of the page to another page and then click the sitemap link to go back to the previous page the changes are lost